# Unable to switch to login page

Tags: testing, karate

I am trying to launch the home page, where it has been automatically navigating to some authorization page. where I am entering the username and password. After clicking on submit it will automatically close and it will come to home page. But in script the driver is not finding the home page after successful authorization. The driver is not switching back to home page again. Below is the code snippet I have tried. Kindly do the needful to resolve this.

Given driver "https://google.com"

- driver.maximize()
- print driver.url
- switchPage('Authorization page') -> page Tile has been used
- print driver.url
- input("//input[@id='username']",'12345')
- input("//input[@id='password']",'12345')
- click("//input[@id='submit']")
- switchPage('https://google.com')
- print driver.url
- click("//input[@id='button']

Comment: Sorry @PeterThomas I have no idea about the process. Hereafter I will do the things correctly. Kindly help me to resolve this issue! Once again sorry for that.

Comment: ok. so I can't really help here. ui automation is really hard and depends on what you are testing and how complex it is. you can try follow this process if you want more help: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test - or at the very least provide a way for anyone else to replicate what you are facing. all the best

Comment: @PeterThomas now  I am  able to get the successful result . But  in headless mode the script get failed in * switchPage('Authorization page')  with the below error.
Error log:-
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
- com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.getPages(WebDriver.java:570)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.lambda$switchPage
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions.retry
- com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.switchPage
- <js>.:anonymous(Unnamed:1)

Kindly do the needful!

Comment: yes things will behave differently in headless mode, this is a known limitation. you are welcome to contribute code to "fix" karate if possible

Comment: @PeterThomas Thanks for the inputs. I am new to Karate UI Automation. If anyone provides the solution for the below issue it will be helpful for us.
Issue Summary:- As part of the UI Flow, We are using Key-Cloak login. Once the URL is launched, Its redirected to Key-Cloak authentication page. When executed in headless mode after key clock login, driver is not re-directed to actual login page.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the driver configuration being used for your tests. **`SwitchPage()`** is working fine when scripts ran in headless mode for **`Chrome`** browser. I guess the same is not supported for **`ChromeDriver`** through karate yet. Below is the sample snippet used to verify this behavior. Hope this helps!.

```
* configure driver = {type: 'chrome', headless: true}
* driver 'https://www.restaurant.com/'
* maximize()
* waitForEnabled('{a:1}Specials').click()
* switchPage('https://specials.restaurant.com/')
* waitUntil("document.readyState == 'complete'")
* screenshot()
```

Comment: Ya @Srinivasu Kaki i will try it out this thing. Thanks for the info!